# How behaves f:view with many defined resource library contracts?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, resource-contracts

We're trying to use the `<f:view contracts="xxx" />` feature from **JSF 2.2**, with many simultaneous contracts, as "contract1,contract2".

In our contract1, we have a file `style1.css`, and in our contract2, a `style2.css`. We include both in our views through `<h:outputStylesheet />` tags.

If I only use `contracts="contract1"` in the view, JSF logs than `style2.css` is missing, which is logical.

If I use `contracts="contract1,contract2"`, JSF imports both `style1.css` and `style2.css`, but with a faulty url (it uses `&con=contract1` instead of `&con=contract2` to get the resource).

Is it a bug? Is it normal? I can't find any documentation about the use of many simultaneous contracts.

Comment: I haven't read the spec on this yet, but it makes logically sense that  all contracts ("themes") should consist of exactly the same resource files. Basically, it aren't the resources which change, but the contents of the resources. The answer would then be to rename those two files to have the same name `style.css`.

Comment: But if each contract have to define all resources, then what is the point to allow many contracts at the same time? If I set `contracts="c1,c2"`, and if c1 and c2 both define all resources, then one of them will always be muted by the other, am I right?

Comment: Hmm, you're perhaps right. I've just read the spec on this, but the spec itself doesn't seem to say anything about using multiple contracts in `<f:view contracts>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's normal behaviour, as I've found in the [Apress Pro JSF and HTML 5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430250100) text book. An excerpt:

> It's possible to map multiple contracts to a single mapping. In that case, it will go through each contract sequentially to look for the required templates. Once a template has been found, it will stop processing other templates.

As to *why* it's allowed, if all it's going to do is pick the first suitable option, I'm with you on the fact that it may be pointless after all.

Reference:

- [Apress Pro JSF and HTML 5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430250100)

Comment: So, that means that JSF looks for the 1st resource, tries to find a matching contract, and then only uses this one for all the following resources? Pointless indeed :-/

Comment: I'd however report it to the JSF spec guys at https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC I believe that the spec is broken here. If a resource is not found (which is easy to check), it should search in the next contract, if any.